# Multiprocessing generates numbers in random orders

Tags: python, python-requests, multiprocessing

I'm trying to get requests from a website and because there are over 200000 requests, I'm trying to use the multiprocessing library in Python.

However, it generates file names in the following order:

```
test-0.json
test-625000.json
test-1250000.json
test-1875000.json
```

What am I doing wrong? here is the MWE

```
import requests
import multiprocessing as mp
from numpy import arange

output_path = "test-"

def read_jsons(file_num):
    output_file_name = output_path + str(file_num) + ".json"
    print (output_file_name)
    url = "www.google.com"
    payload = {}
    response = requests.request("GET", url,  data = payload)
    json_str = str(response.text.encode("utf8"), 'utf-8')
    with open(output_file_name, "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(json_str)

p = mp.Pool(8)
p.map(read_jsons, arange(0, 20000000, 1))
p.close()
p.join()
```

Comment: Multithreading/multiprocessing always happens in an unpredictable order. This program spawns millions of processes, which will be queued and executed in almost random order.

Comment: That's strange because if you comment everything below `url ="www.google.com"`, you'd get it in order?

Comment: Your requests to google will presumably take different times (you're dealing with a remote system and your request packets won't always take the same route to get there). You can't guarantee the order that multithreaded processes will execute, but computers are logical and similar processes take similar times to run. If you remove the complete randomness of internet traffic, you might well get it in order. Is the order important to you (and you want a solution) or were you just asking why this happens?

Comment: It is not important for me, but I would like to know how to do in order as well.